# Removing an event listener as well as a sprite at the same time AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, event-handling, removechild

I’m having trouble removing the an event listener as well as the sprite at the same time. I currently get an error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access
>   a property or method of a null object
>   reference.

And if I comment out removeChild, I have no error but, obviously, the sprite remains on the screen. Any ideas how I can rid myself of that error?

```
     //Bullet extends Sprite Class
     bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
     mc.addChild(bullet);
     bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shoot);

     function shoot(e:Event):void {
        var shot:Bullet = e.currentTarget as Bullet;
        //check shot is outside the frame
        if (shot.x < 0 - shot.width || shot.x > stage.stageWidth || shot.y > 525)
        {
            //trying to remove the thing and it's listener
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type,arguments.callee);
            e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(shot);
        }
        else
        {
            shot.setInMotion();
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't forget to put in shot.y < 0 - shot.height :)

Comment: Just a point: in general when adding the event listener, use weak references i.e. addEventListener(Event, shoot, false, 0, true), this allows the components to be garbage collected and acts similar to removing the eventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from a missing **var** before bullet:Bullet, I don't see anything wrong in the example code. You should set a breakpoint right after:

```
var shot:Bullet = e.currentTarget as Bullet;
```

And figure out why **shot** is null. I suspect there is something amiss in a piece of code outside of the little bit you're providing as the example. If the code is working with only the removeChild line commented out, it tells me that e.currentTarget is not null, but that it's also not a reference to an instance of type Bullet (i.e. the "as" cast is returning null).

Comment: You know, you were correct—I forgot I had left a trace outside the conditional statement from earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing these lines
Maybe the reference to e.currentTarget is getting lost through the object references

```
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type,arguments.callee);
e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(shot);
```

to

```
e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(shot);
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type,arguments.callee);
```